# Passing variable in window.location in Java script is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass a variable in java script but it's not working:

```
window.location.href = "calulator?dist=" + calculate;
```

output is like :

```
http://localhost/jspractice/calulator?dist=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%205*%20%20%20%205
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine. What's the problem?

Comment: how did you get your calculate?

Comment: "%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%205*%20%20%20%205" is decoded to "        5*    5", you want that passed or the calculated value of 25?

Comment: @NewbeeDev Looks like OP URL-encoded the value `        5*      5` (note the spaces.

Comment: You just have to encode/decode your URL

Answer (score 0):

You just have to decode the received URL with `decodeURIComponent()`

See example :

```js
var URL = "%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%205*%20%20%20%205";

var decodedURL = decodeURIComponent(URL);

console.log(decodedURL);
```